# Why does Mercurial's ssh:// URL use two slashes before the path?

Tags: url, mercurial

Example Mercurial URL: `ssh://myhost//path/to/repo`

Why two slashes? The hostname is already specified. Why it does not work like `http://myhost/path/to/page` where only one slash is sufficient?

Comment: Does it really? Or does it work as `ssh://myhost/path/to/repo`?

Comment: My guess is that it has to do with what the physical path is on the server hosting Mercurial.  Typically, you would log in to your home directory via ssh.  So, there perhaps should be a difference between ssh://myhost/path/to/page (which would map to /home/username/path/to/page) and ssh://myhost//path/to/page (which maps to /path/to/page).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See [this url](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#urls), which says this:

> path is relative to the remote user's home directory by default.
>   Use an extra slash at the start of a path to specify an absolute path:

Comment: What is the home directory on Windows?

Answer (score 6):

Usually a URL is formed in the following way: `scheme://user@host:port/path`, with the `user@` and `:port` part being optional. This means the first `/` is the separator between the host part and the path part: **it is not part of the path**.

Then the path can either be absolute (starts with a `/`) or relative to the home directory of the user (no `/`).

This is just a reminder that the paths used by `rsync` or `scp` are not urls.